# Prevent cold boot attack on running laptop by overwriting ram

Tags: attacks, boot

I'd like to use my laptop as a recording device when I leave home, but there would still be the possibility for a cold boot attack or with DDR3 RAM even warm boot attack is possible as I have read.

Could one overwrite RAM before leaving the laptop locked and make cold boot impossible that way?

I found this: 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/sdmem.1.html

Will `sdmem` really overwrite the RAM of a running system?
Is it possible to write a script that does this every time I lock my pc?

Comment: we do not write programs for people

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `sdmem` tool for your purposes.

If you use only bash without any desktop environment you can simple [add your command to $HOME/.bash_logout script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-execute-command-when-i-log-out-of-linux-unix-shell/).

In case of using GDM you can try to append `sdmem` command to `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` file.

Also you can to look [this](https://superuser.com/questions/127454/run-script-on-logout-shutdown-ubuntu) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks i am using normal unity desktop and am quite a noob regarding scripts and linux but i will look more into it.
If you could tell me how to apply this to unity it would be great ofc.